# POST multipart/form-data with file data from URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call an API using javascript that contains a file in the POST request. The file is located at another URL that I have to grab before calling the API. I think I need to use a fetch to get the file data as a blob and then pass it along to the post request.

I have a working example in CURL but can't work out the syntax to translate it into JS.

**Working example in CURL:**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Token token=****' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' 
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' -F file=@/User/somefile.pdf -F file_name=nameForFile 
  -F is_shared=true -F targetable_id=1 -F targetable_type=Lead -X POST "https://endpoint.com/api/documents"
```

**Javascript:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
fetch("http://wheremyfileis.com/file.pdf")
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(fileData => {
        var fileBlob = new Blob((fileData );

formData.append("targetable_id", 1);
formData.append("targetable_type", "Lead");
formData.append("file", fileBlob);

var headers = {"Authorization": "Token token=***", "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"};
var options = { headers: headers, body: "Hello world"};
var url = "https://endpoint.com/api/documents";
client.request.post(url, options)
 .then (
   function(data) { console.log(data); },
   function(error) {console.log(error);}
);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to show your token in JS?

Comment: The token is just in his example. In the app it’s pulled in dynamically from the Param config